# Why am I getting the same result when using p.adjust for the Holm and Bonferroni methods?

Tags: r, statistics, bonferroni

I've run several regressions and I'm trying to see if any of the significant findings hold after a multiple comparison adjustment. I know that Bonferroni adjustment is more conservative than Holm adjustment, so I would expect the outputs to be different, however they weren't. One of the values varied slightly, but not as much as I would have expected given that one of these tests is supposed to be less conservative than the other. I tried another correction method and got similar results. Is there something wrong with my syntax or is this a normal result?

```
p.vect <- c(.003125, .008947)
p.adjust(p.vect, method = "bonferroni", n=80)
[1] 0.25000 0.71576

p.adjust(p.vect, method = "holm", n=80)
[1] 0.250000 0.706813

p.adjust(p.vect, method = "hochberg", n = 80)
[1] 0.250000 0.706813
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holm and Hochberg just don't differ from each other for `length(p)==2`.

Given that `lp` is `length(na.omit(p))` (equal to 2 in this case), and `p` is the vector of probabilities, here's the code for `method=="holm"`:

```
i <- seq_len(lp)   ## (1,2)
o <- order(p)      ## (1,2)
ro <- order(o)     ## (1,2) 
pmin(1, cummax((n + 1L - i) * p[o]))[ro]  ## c(80,79)*p
```

and the code for `method=="hochberg"`:

```
i <- lp:1L                        ## (2,1) 
o <- order(p, decreasing = TRUE)  ## (2,1)
ro <- order(o)                    ## (2,1) 
pmin(1, cummin((n + 1L - i) * p[o]))[ro]  ## c(80,79)*p[c(2,1)][c(2,1)]
```

If you step through the details you can see how they give the same answer for your case.  (Holm uses `cummax()` on the sorted vector of adjusted probabilities, Hochberg uses `cummin()` on the reverse-sorted vector, but neither of these changes anything in this case.)

Bonferroni is `pmin(1, n*p)`.  In this case the only difference is a factor of 80/79 on the second element (Hochberg and Holm multiply by `(n+1-i)` = c(80,79), Bonferroni multiplies by `n`=79.)

You can print out the code by typing `p.adjust` by itself, or in a prettier form [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed5faf4ac36ee5de5f00185f4b5958a960eecbb7/src/library/stats/R/p.adjust.R)

Comment: Thanks! I just ran Holm and Hochberg corrections on a vector of 144 p values, and got exactly the same results (granted they were mostly 1s). Does that seem right?